# Is Westworld an isolated part of the country or something else?

Tags: westworld-2016

In Westworld (2016) we see this vast area of land that is the stereotypical 'western' locale with scrubland, some prairie, a few nice buttes, and so on.

On top of one of the larger mesas is a complex that houses the maintenance crew and developers. They even mention in casual conversation about rotating back home.

Is Westworld located in some sort of giant holodeck like building, or is it in a remote locale? (I was thinking something Jurassic park like since it's written by Michael Crichton).

Comment: Well the original was a large area that had to be travelled to so I'd imagine the same applies here.

Comment: @Paulie_D they do show the newcomers entering in a fancy futuristic train, and then moving on to a door that looks like a train car door for that period, which makes me even more curious.  I was thinking something like 'holodeck' when I saw that

Comment: I haven't seen the ep yet, but the impression I got from reading up is that the location was deliberately left vague.

Comment: As I recall there was a train in the original too.

Comment: There's no indication of "holodeckness". In fact the whole thing is built around physical interaction, with android people, horses etc. Is it a controlled environment, probably, but there's nothing to show this isn't actually a remote physical *real* open-air location

Comment: Do you want to create the [tag:westworld-2016] wiki?

Comment: @Adamant Sure, I can take care of it

Comment: My fuzzy memory was telling me that the original was on a space station, but Wikipedia tells me that the sequel, Futureworld, included a section that *simulated* a space station, so that's probably where that was from.

Comment: So it's on an island, and maybe near China?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At https://www.discoverwestworld.com/#explore you can see a map. It is definitely a real place, with a sea on the western edge, not a holodeck type of simulation. The map is labeled "Topology survey of the park, commissioned under the command of the United States Government."  I have heard speculation that it is anything from somewhere out west, to an artificial island, to Mars (with the talk of rotating home and all), but other than dialog and the map, we don't have much to go on yet. There might be some clues hidden in the chat bot at the site, which says all sorts of clues and crazy things depending on if you are asking the right questions.

Comment: Rotating homes?

Comment: @M.Button there's a dup question on the Movies/TV site here: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65582/where-is-the-westworld-park-actually-located. would you mind posting your answer there too? I'm happy to do it myself, but then you wouldn't get the reputation.

Answer (score 9):

It appears to be in (or near) Monument Valley, Arizona.

[image]
**Westworld Opening Scene**

[image]
**Real Monument Valley**

Interestingly, the 'nature' scenes in the episodes were filmed in [Castle Valley, Utah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_Valley,_Utah) which is some 175 miles away.

> The backdrop for Westworld’s opening episodes is Castle Valley in
> Utah. Nolan explains,
>
> “When John Ford got bored of shooting in Monument Valley, he sent
> scouts all over the Southwest to find something even more visually
> spectacular. They found Castle Valley.”
>
> <sup><sub>[Will HBO’s Much-Delayed Westworld Be the Next Game of Thrones–Style Hit?](http://www.vulture.com/2016/08/is-hbo-westworld-the-next-game-of-thrones.html)</sub></sup>

---

That being said, the *actual location* hasn't been explicitly stated within the show (yet).

Answer (score 1):

In the opening episode of season 2, some Chinese soldiers are told to leave the park (which is, I think, described as an island) as their government has given Delos control over it.

In the rest of season 2, we see that Arnold built a house in a city "within reach" of the park, which looks like Hong Kong. As such, Westworld (and the other parks) are probably located on an island off China.