# Where in the world is Westworld's park?

Tags: real-location, westworld-2016

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142883/how-do-westworld-guests-and-hosts-travel-into-the-park) addresses the question of how guests get into the park, but no one knows exactly where it is.
[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142124/is-westworld-an-isolated-part-of-the-country-or-something-else) asks if Westworld is an isolated part of the country, while the one I am asking now provides evidence for being an island, on Earth, and asks where such an island may be.

So far, we have some information about the location of the park:

- **It borders an ocean, we have the size of the park based on a scale, and we have potential coordinates on the title bar:**

[image]

- **It is an island:**

> From the *Westworld Terms and Conditions:*
>
> INVESTIGATIONS/VIOLATIONS: If Delos, Inc. or any Delos Entity believes, in its sole discretion, that a violation of these Terms has occurred, it may take any and all corrective action it deems appropriate without notice, including **contacting local authorities on the mainland**. All human-on-human crimes taking place within the Delos Destinations compound will first be investigated by Delos, Inc.; Delos, Inc. has successfully avoided providing personal data in response to a legal process involving outside court entities for its entire history of existence. However, Delos, Inc. reserves the right to disclose personal information requested by a law enforcement agency, and shall have no liability to you for such disclosure.

Given the above information, and introducing more if you find it,

- What is a plausible, existing island that matches the size of Westworld given by the map, as well as the ~coordinates given on the top bar?
- If there is not an existing island at around this location, where would this island to be, plausibly??

Comment: @Valorum Edited question accordingly, thank you

Comment: Alas, this remains a dupe. Any answer that covers this would also cover the other question.

Comment: @Valorum Unfortunately no answer on the other question actually covered "where would this island be" nor would any info "the island would be here" cover the alleged dupe of "is it in an isolated part of the US"

Comment: The "or something else" part of that question basically covers everything you've asked. Elements of *this question* (references to "the mainland", for example) would actually make a pretty solid, albeit speculative answer to that question.

Comment: @Valorum What would you suggest I do? Editing their question to give it a meaning they did not intend would not work, nor would answering their question when I myself do not know the answer.

Comment: Actually, this really isn't a dupe of my question.  At the time, I didn't know it was an island, and that 'something else' meant more like a holo-deck like thing, or if it was an island.  I'm asking a general 'what is it', and Zxyrra is asking 'where'.  Post this info in my question as an answer, and I'd accept it.

Comment: @CBredlow - It's hardly proof positive though. Many isolated communities refer to the outside world as "the mainland" **without meaning that they're literally on an island**.

Comment: @Valorum We know there is an ocean - "sea" so I think it can be argued that this **is a literal island.**

Comment: @Zxyrra - Ocean on one side doesn't an island make. Just ask France.

Comment: @Valorum could we continue this in a discussion? And even if this is not necessarily a physical island, this question is built assuming it is one, and in the least abstract sense it *would be* an island -- so the statement still stands " 'Where is a park with these specifics' is different from 'what is a park with less specifics' "

Comment: Even an ocean on _most_ sides wouldn't make it an island. Canada.

Comment: @Zxyrra - One of my concerns is that this question is built on a false (or at least unproven) assumption, that Westworld is on an island when the mesa and other features would strongly suggest mid-West US. That being said, we see some truly enormous cranes, capable of making entire valleys so all bets are off.

Comment: @MrLister - [Well, indeed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OwN7eYZseI).

Comment: @Valorum Regardless of if it is an island - a subject for another debate - How do you suggest I continue now that this is closed. Editing their question to give it a meaning they did not intend would not work, nor would answering their question when I myself do not know the answer. If this is "an exact duplicate" what course of action must I take to find an answer to my Q?

Comment: @Zxyrra - I would personally suggest that you simply wait. If and when an answer exists regarding the actual location of Westworld, it will almost certainly be added to the dupe question within a few minutes/hours. If you want to waste some rep, you could sling a bounty on it, although I deeply doubt that'll make the answer come quicker.